# Instance initialisation, where to put?

Tags: c#, instance

Basically one of my instances (theNode) needs to take in a variable as it's in take parameter however, I need to declare the instance globally (not sure if this is the correct wording) along with the other instances so the data is always stored through out the lifetime of the programs execution.

Example of where I'd like it to be placed beside:

```
Tree theTree = new Tree();
UsersInput theInput = new UsersInput();
```

Where it is placed:

```
while (!attempt)
{
    int temp = theInput.TheUsersInput();
    Node theNode = new Node(temp);
    theTree.Add(temp);
    theNode.PrintNodes();
    attempt = theInput.AddMoreNumbers();
}
```

Anyone got any suggestions how I could get around this without using bad programming practices?

Comment: How can the object be globally accessive through out the lifetime of programs execution if the necessary input parameter is unknown to it? Also - use proper methods for your methods - `TheUsersInput()` is totally meaningless.

Comment: "*I need to declare the instance globally...without using bad programming practices?*" Using globals is generally bad programming practice.

Comment: @Tarec That's what I'm asking for suggestions with..lol. What do you mean use proper methods for my methods? What's improper about my method? Do you mean use proper names? If so it is not a meaningless name because it gets the users input then returns it.. It does exactly what it says.

Comment: @user3245390 To clarify my statement. If you want to follow good programming practices, you should try to refactor the code so that you no longer need to use a global. There's not enough information in this question to tell what that might look like or how difficult it would be to implement. In some cases, using a global might actually be warranted if the equivalent code without the global is absolutely horrendous.

Comment: @user3245390 Yes, I meant the name. It doesn't do what it says. It doesn't tell you whether it creates new object or returns reference to an internal one. Also `UsersInput` object named `theInput` returns from `TheUsersInput` method a result of type int - that's messy. You have similar names for different object types. It shouldn't be made a method at all, but a getter property instead. Consider those to be good programming practices, especially if you're sharing the code with anyone.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I was actually using the word global wrong, I just thought it meant so other parts of the class could see it. I said I wasn't sure if the wording was correct in the OP.

Comment: @Tarec I personally agree that to a much lesser extent the naming of that class isn't too great but it was only meant to contain one method (I have yet to re-factor my code). Okay, I'll bear that in mind in the future to use more precise naming.

Answer (score 1):

You can make them `static` fields in one of the classes. Something like this:

```
class Program
{
    public static Node theNode;

    void Main()
    {
        ...
        while (!attempt)
        {
            int temp = theInput.TheUsersInput();
            theNode = new Node(temp);
            theTree.Add(temp);
            theNode.PrintNodes();
            attempt = theInput.AddMoreNumbers();
        }
        // you can start using theNode globally from this point
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding how this would help my issue. I have no issue with theTree and theInput, I have an issue with theNode

Comment: Not really (I tried it), the reason why I instantiated it was because I need the data to exist till the program is exited. Now everytime the method has been completed and rerun the previous data is lost :(.

Comment: Hi Migol can you explain to me the difference between a `public static` instance var and a `public` instance var? I'm assuming `public` is global to only this class, while `public static` is global to all classes?

Comment: You are coorect. `static` means that this can be accessed via `ClassName.PropName` format without the need to have this classes instance.

Answer (score 0):

A variable which is not "local" to some method (or accessor etc.) but instead resides directly uncer the `class` (or `struct`) declaration, is called a **field** in C#.

A field can be either `static` (only one field exists for the class ever) or non-static (each *instance* of the class, i.e. each object of that type, has its own "version" of the field).

Note that in C# a variable must be declared inside a `class` or `struct`.

Examples:

```
namespace N
{
  public static Tree TheTree = new Tree();  // ILLEGAL (not inside a class)!
}

namespace N
{
  class YourClass
  {
    public static Tree TheOneTree = new Tree();  // OK, static

    public Tree TheOtherTree = new Tree();  // OK, instance

    void Method()
    {
      var theUltimateTree = new Tree();  // OK, local variable
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

However, you should consider using a *property* instead of a field if you need it to be `public` as above. Fields should often be `private` (the default accessibility for class members).